# Tkinter .after() method freezes and dont update gui after sometime

Tags: python, tkinter, updates, freeze

Firstly, I'm new python and tkinter. I want to read some values with OPC XML DA and show them on tkinter gui with automatic update every ten seconds. But OPC XML DA response takes too long time. Because of this I parse them so I have two scripts. First script read values and write logs to .txt and its works fine. Second one is, read this value from .txt and show them tkinter GUI. The problem is start here, Second script works fine but after some time or if ı minimize to icon status, GUI is freezes. Program is running background fine but Tkinter GUI freezes.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
import json



timeperiod=10
my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.title(" ALARM MONITOR")
my_w.geometry("1500x800")

def window():
         
            with open("alarm_log3.txt", "r") as fp:
                b = json.load(fp)

                now=datetime.now()
                date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ")
                date_time1 = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                ss_namex = tk.Label(my_w, text= date_time, width=10, fg='white', bg='blue', font=('Arial',15))
                ss_namex.grid(row=0,column=4)
                ss_namex1 = tk.Label(my_w, text= date_time1, width=10, fg='white', bg='blue', font=('Arial',15))
                ss_namex1.grid(row=0,column=5)
                for i in range (0,21,1):            
                   
                    if ( b[i][3] == 'FM0' and ( b[i][4] == 'false' and b[i][5] == 'false' and b[i][6] == 'false' and b[i][7] == 'false' and b[i][8] == 'false'  and b[i][9] == 'false' )):
                        color ='green2'
                    elif( b[i][3] == 'FM0' and ( b[i][4] != 'false' or b[i][5] != 'false' or b[i][6] != 'false' or b[i][7] != 'false' or b[i][8] != 'false'  or b[i][9] != 'false' )):
                        color ='yellow2'
                    elif b[i][3] != 'FM0' :
                        color= 'red2'
                    else:
                        color='blue2'




                    baslik1 = tk.Label(my_w, text='ST', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        
                    baslik2 = tk.Label(my_w, text='STA' , width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik2.grid(row=1,column=2) 

                    baslik3 = tk.Label(my_w, text='STB', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik3.grid(row=1,column=3)

                    baslik4 = tk.Label(my_w, text='STC', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik4.grid(row=1,column=4)

                    baslik5 = tk.Label(my_w, text='Codex', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik5.grid(row=1,column=5)
        
                    baslik6 = tk.Label(my_w, text='Codey' , width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik6.grid(row=1,column=6) 

                    baslik7 = tk.Label(my_w, text='Codez', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik7.grid(row=1,column=7)

                    baslik8 = tk.Label(my_w, text='Codea', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik8.grid(row=1,column=8)

                    baslik9 = tk.Label(my_w, text='Codeb', width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik9.grid(row=1,column=9)
        
                    baslik10 = tk.Label(my_w, text='Codec' , width=10, fg='white', bg='blue2', font=('Arial',15))
                    baslik10.grid(row=1,column=10) 
     
                       
                    ss_name1=('ss{y}1'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name2=('ss{y}2'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name3=('ss{y}3'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name4=('ss{y}4'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name5=('ss{y}5'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name6=('ss{y}6'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name7=('ss{y}7'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name8=('ss{y}8'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name9=('ss{y}9'.format(y=i))
                    ss_name10=('ss{y}10'.format(y=i))
                    

                    ss_name1 = tk.Label(my_w, text=(i+1), width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name1.grid(row=i+2,column=1)
        
                    ss_name2 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][1], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name2.grid(row=i+2,column=2) 

                    ss_name3 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][2], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name3.grid(row=i+2,column=3)

                    ss_name4 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][3], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name4.grid(row=i+2,column=4)

                    ss_name5 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][4], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name5.grid(row=i+2,column=5)
        
                    ss_name6 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][5], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name6.grid(row=i+2,column=6) 

                    ss_name7 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][6], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name7.grid(row=i+2,column=7)

                    ss_name8 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][7], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name8.grid(row=i+2,column=8)

                    ss_name9 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][8], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name9.grid(row=i+2,column=9)

                    ss_name10 = tk.Label(my_w, text=b[(i)][9], width=10, fg='black', bg=color, font=('Arial',15))
                    ss_name10.grid(row=i+2,column=10)
        
                   
  
            my_w.after(10000, window)
    
    
window()

my_w.mainloop()
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnJJD.png)

Thank you,

i tried many things but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I'm not an expert with tkinter but generally you shouldn't create GUI elements again and again but create them once and then change only content and other attributes like colors.

Comment: As Michael Butscher mentioned your problem is due to creating labels over and over again. This basically stacks the newly created labels on top of the old ones so visually you don't see them but they are there and thus you are overwhelming your application over time. That said you should spend some time learning how to dynamically create labels. Having to write them all in manually when you have a large number of them will become a problem for maintaining code later.

Comment: You can use a callback function, find examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843465/12621346

Comment: Before your comments, I have no idea about the problem. Some time ago I took the code that created the Gui element outside of the .after() method ( ı create one time) and fixed the problem by putting label_namex.configure() inside. Thank you for your comments.