# How do I build a countdown function inside a tkinter class object?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, time, countdown

I've built a function that counts down on the screen. I want the number label to disappear after the last number, but instead it displays the number 1. What's going on here?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class countdown_app:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk() 
        self.root.geometry('500x500')
        self.countdown_function(7) # Argument is number where countdown starts
        self.root.mainloop()

    def countdown_function(self, count):
        self.count_label = tk.Label(self.root, text=count, fg='black', font=('Arial', 26))
        self.count_label.place(x=250, y=250)
        self.count_label.update()   
        if count > 0:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            self.countdown_function(count-1)
        else:
            self.count_label.destroy()
            self.count_label.update()

# Create an instance of the app
countdown_app()
```

Comment: Find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843465/12621346)

Answer (score 0):

You have written 2 methods in your class.
First method `__init__` just creates a tk Window. Here you are not providing the class with the initial count argument, and you are later on calling the function with this initial value of 7.
You better do: `def __init__(self, count):`
then: `self.count = count`.
So you can call it: `countdown_app(7)`

The second method, `countdown_function`, creates a label every time it is called.
It would be much better to create the label within the `__init__` method (that is precisely the purpose of this method), and then call the countdown_function to update that label text or destroy it.

Also, it is bad practice to use `time.sleep` on a GUI, since it will make it hang. Rather use after method: `self.after(300, self.countdown_function)`

And finally, the reason for the label not to be destroyed is simply because you are defining the root.mainloop() in the **init** method.
You can create a class for countdown_function (from tk, or tk.Frame), like below to overcome that problem:

```
class countdown_app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, count):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = count
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.count_label = tk.Label(self, text=self.count, fg='black', font=('Arial', 26))
        self.count_label.place(x=250, y=250)
        self.countdown_function(self.count)  # Argument is number where countdown starts

    def countdown_function(self, count: int):
        self.count = self.count - 1
        if count > 0:
            self.count_label['text']=self.count
            self.after(300, self.countdown_function, self.count)
        else:
            self.count_label.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create an instance of the app
    App = countdown_app(7)
    App.mainloop()
```